# javascript array.toString() element separation

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to separate `array.toString()` with semicolons instead of commas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the "join" method on the array - `array.join(";")`

Answer (score 9):

Check out [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). It takes an argument for the separator.

```
alert(myArray.join(';'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.toString().replace(/,/g,';');
array.join(';');
```

Comment: This would fail if the elements have commas in the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayAsString = array.toString();
var whatYouWant = arrayAsString.replace(/,/g, ';');
```

Comment: This replaces only the first comma

Comment: This would fail if the elements have commas in the values.

Comment: @slandau That replaces only one comma. Use a regex to replace all commas: `replace(/,/g, ';')`

Comment: Of course, if commas can be inside the values, than `join` is the only way to go

Answer (score 0):

Though default separator for the join() method is comma(','), you can use other separators also. Refer this [JavaScript Array Object : join() Method tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/object-property-method/array-join.php).